# Will en0 always be Wi-Fi on an iOS device?

Tags: ios, network-programming, ip

I’m trying to get the IP address of the wifi interface on iOS devices using `getifaddrs()` and searching for the `en0` name. This is working fine, but it assumes that `en0` is always Wi-Fi. Is there some way to ensure that the interface I’m querying is specifically Wi-Fi for future proofing?

Comment: no, not always. e.g. consider an old pre-wifi macbook. it depends on how the EFI firmware and/or IOS enumerate the devices. en0 could very likely be the wired ethernet port, and en1 be wifi.

Answer (score 1):

I use the following to find the wifi information by looking for a device which has a BSSID for the wifi station. It will also have a SSID.

The following class method returns the wifi info dictionary only. It is a simple extension to also return the device label (`ifname` variable). It is usually en0, as you have noted, but this would work as a way to make sure you pick up the wifi if it was not en0 in the future.

```
+ (NSDictionary *)getWifiInfo {
    NSDictionary *ret=nil;

    // Get the supported interfaces.
    NSArray *ifs = (__bridge_transfer id)CNCopySupportedInterfaces();

    // Find one with a BSSID and return that. This should be the wifi.
    for (NSString *ifnam in ifs) {
        NSDictionary *info = (__bridge_transfer id)CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo((__bridge CFStringRef)ifnam);

        NSLog(@"Network device found = %@", info.description);

        if (info[(__bridge NSString *)kCNNetworkInfoKeyBSSID]) {
            // Return this as it should be the right one given it has a MAC address for the station
            ret=info;
        }
    }

    NSLog(@"Exit: returning wifi info = %@", ret.description);

    return ret;
}
```

Once you have the device label based on BSSID, you can then use `getifaddrs` to get its IP, gateway etc knowing it is the wifi device.

**NB** This returns nil in the iOS simulator as there is no wifi detected, so for testing you need some workaround code to meet your needs.

A hacky option is to find the IP address with an associated MAC of `02:00:00:00:00:00`. iOS hides the MAC address from coders and it has this value.

Comment: One issue with this answer is CaptureNetwork is deprecated in iOS 9.

Comment: @codecaffeine Ouch. Did not realize that. The app I'm finishing relies on the BSSID to identify different access points onto the same network. Worse seems that deprecated here means obsolete beyond support for compile/link!!! Seems the alternative is to use `[NEHotspotHelper supportedNetworkInterfaces]` but that requires some sort of approval and its not been easy to get.

Comment: @codecaffeine Seems an interesting conversation is taking place on the forums with some feedback from Apple taking place. The indication is that it is being discussed, but they are not saying anything concrete yet. Plenty unhappy coders out there it seems. See https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/31340

Comment: @codecaffeine FYI, looks like iOS9 GM put back the functionality, although still marked as deprecated. Apple have request people raise their use case in a defect. See the previous forum link.

Comment: ... and the CaptiveNetwork functionality used here still works on iOS 10